# Executing function after data loads into view SwiftUI

Tags: json, swift, swiftui

I want the Snapshot function to be executed once my ContentView has loaded in all the network data. I have no problem with the API call, I just simply want the Snapshot function to run after all data has loaded into ContentView.

Expected result after pressing button:
[Expected result after pressing button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9yfgI.png)

Actual result after pressing button:
[Actual result after pressing button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ZETh.png)

**ContentView.swift**

```
extension View {
    
    func Snapshot() -> UIImage {
        let controller = UIHostingController(rootView: self)
        let view = controller.view
        
        let targetSize = controller.view.intrinsicContentSize
        view?.bounds = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: targetSize)
        view?.backgroundColor = .clear
        
        let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: targetSize)
        
        return renderer.image { _ in
            view?.drawHierarchy(in: controller.view.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
        }
    }
    
}



struct ContentView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var FetchResults = fetchResults()
    
    var contentView: some View {
        
        ContentView()
        
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Group {
            if FetchResults.dataHasLoaded {
                
                VStack {
                    Text(FetchResults.clout.postFound?.body ?? "n/a")
                        .padding()
                        .background(Color.blue)
                        .mask(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 30, style: .continuous))
                        .shadow(color: Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1)).opacity(0.3), radius: 10, x: 0, y:10)
                        .padding()
                        .frame(maxWidth: 300)
                    
                    
                }
                
                Button(action: {
                    
                    let image = contentView.Snapshot()
                    print(image)
                    
                }, label:{Text("press me to print view")})
                
                
            } else {
                
                Text("loading data")
                
            }
        }
        
        
        
    }
}
```

**GotPost.swift** -- my ViewModel running the API call

```
class fetchResults: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var clout = Cloutington()
    @Published var dataHasLoaded = false
    
    
    init() {
        
        getData { clout in
            self.clout = clout
        }
        
    }
    
    private func getData(completion: @escaping (Cloutington) -> ()) {
        
        let parameters =  "{\r\n \"PostHashHex\": \"2f9633c2460f23d9d5690fe9fd058457ebeb01f6f75805aa426cdaab90a1f4b4\"\r\n}"
        let postData = parameters.data(using: .utf8)
        var request =  URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://bitclout.com/api/v0/get-single-post")!,timeoutInterval: Double.infinity)
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.httpBody = postData
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        
        let task =  URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (responseData, response, error) in

            print(error)
            print(response)
            print(responseData)
            
            if let resData = responseData {
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                
                do
                {
                    let finalData = try decoder.decode(Cloutington.self, from: resData)
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {

                        completion(finalData)
                        self.dataHasLoaded = true

                    }
                    
                }
                catch (let error)
                {
                    print(error)
                }

            }
            
        }
        task.resume()
        
    }
    
}
```

**PostFound.swift** -- model parsing JSON data

````
struct Cloutington: Decodable {
    
    var postFound: PostFound?
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case postFound = "PostFound"
        
    }
    
}

struct PostFound: Decodable {
    
    var id: String?
    var postHashHex, posterPublicKeyBase58Check, parentStakeID, body: String?
    var imageURLs: [String]?
    //    var recloutedPostEntryResponse: JSONNull?
    var creatorBasisPoints, stakeMultipleBasisPoints: Int?
    var timestampNanos: Double?
    var isHidden: Bool?
    var confirmationBlockHeight: Int?
    var inMempool: Bool?
    var profileEntryResponse: ProfileEntryResponse?
    var likeCount, diamondCount: Int?
    var isPinned: Bool?
    var commentCount, recloutCount: Int?
    var diamondsFromSender: Int?
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case postHashHex = "PostHashHex"
        case posterPublicKeyBase58Check = "PosterPublicKeyBase58Check"
        case parentStakeID = "ParentStakeID"
        case body = "Body"
        case imageURLs = "ImageURLs"
        case creatorBasisPoints = "CreatorBasisPoints"
        case stakeMultipleBasisPoints = "StakeMultipleBasisPoints"
        case timestampNanos = "TimestampNanos"
        case isHidden = "IsHidden"
        case confirmationBlockHeight = "ConfirmationBlockHeight"
        case inMempool = "InMempool"
        case profileEntryResponse = "ProfileEntryResponse"
        case likeCount = "LikeCount"
        case diamondCount = "DiamondCount"
        case isPinned = "IsPinned"
        case commentCount = "CommentCount"
        case recloutCount = "RecloutCount"
        case diamondsFromSender = "DiamondsFromSender"
    }
}

// MARK: - ProfileEntryResponse
struct ProfileEntryResponse: Decodable {
    var publicKeyBase58Check, username, profileEntryResponseDescription, profilePic: String?
    var isHidden, isReserved, isVerified: Bool?
    var coinPriceBitCloutNanos, stakeMultipleBasisPoints: Int?
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case publicKeyBase58Check = "PublicKeyBase58Check"
        case username = "Username"
        case profileEntryResponseDescription = "Description"
        case profilePic = "ProfilePic"
        case isHidden = "IsHidden"
        case isReserved = "IsReserved"
        case isVerified = "IsVerified"
        case coinPriceBitCloutNanos = "CoinPriceBitCloutNanos"
        case stakeMultipleBasisPoints = "StakeMultipleBasisPoints"
    }
} ```

Really appreciate the help
````

Comment: It is a computed property so you are likely recreating the content view vs actually taking a snapshot of the screen. Try `self.Snapshot()`

Comment: @DeveloperDank If you use self.Snapshot(), it will include "press me to print view" too in the snapshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to get more and better help in general if you follow the [Swift API Design Guidelines](https://swift.org/documentation/api-design-guidelines/) for naming types and variables. That means using lower case for the initial letters of properties and methods, and upper case for the initial letters of types. I understand that you may come from a platform like C# where the conventions are different. But when you don't do things the Swift way (or worse, as in your code, where you do both!), you make it harder for us to understand your code.

Also, this is a bad pattern:

> ```
> @ObservedObject var FetchResults = fetchResults()
> ```

The problem is that SwiftUI doesn't understand the ownership of the `FetchResults` object, and will recreate it each time the view is recreated. In this case, you should use `@StateObject` instead:

```
@StateObject var fetchResults = FetchResults()
```

Check out [this article by Paul Hudson](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/whats-the-difference-between-observedobject-state-and-environmentobject) for guidance on when to use `@StateObject` and when to use `@ObservableObject`.

However, that won't fix the problem you posted about. Your code creates the snapshot by saying `contentView.Snapshot()`, which calls your `contentView` computed property, which creates a new `ContentView` from scratch, which creates a new, unloaded `FetchResults` (regardless of whether you use `@ObservedObject` or `@StateObject`).

You need to reuse the `FetchResults` that has already loaded its data, so just say `self.snapshot()` instead:

```
Button(
    action: {
        let image = self.snapshot()
        print(image)
    },
    label: {
        Text("press me to print view")
    }
)
```

Comment: Rob you legend! Thank you and really appreciate the advice 